# Why multiple insertions in postgresql db allows duplicate primary keys?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with 2 foreign keys that form primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE CityToCity
(
     City1_ID INTEGER REFERENCES City NOT NULL,
     City2_ID INTEGER REFERENCES City NOT NULL
           CHECK (City2_ID != City1_ID),
     PRIMARY KEY (City1_ID, City2_ID)
);
```

And here I try to add some info there. The code below works well.

```
INSERT INTO "CityToCity" ("City1_ID", "City2_ID")
VALUES (1, 2), (2, 1);
```

But if I try to insert these rows one by one we get an exception that

> this primary key already exists

```
INSERT INTO "CityToCity" ("City1_ID", "City2_ID")
VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO "CityToCity" ("City1_ID", "City2_ID")
VALUES (2, 1);
```

What is the difference between these two insert operations?

Comment: Maybe they exist because the previous insert operation is done? Try to drop the table :) (or just use other values) and run only insert one by one and see the result

Comment: Yeah this is happening because you have not `DELETE`ed `TRUNCAT`ed the previous values. This is not a good PK as you would expect `City1_ID` and `City2_ID` to be repeated if they are child records in a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship.

Comment: Most likely you forgot to clean the table between those two tests. It works well. See running example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/spHm2ruAjMS6Hz6nvB7acj/0

Comment: Closing as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want (city1, city2) and (city2,city1) to represent the same relationship then do not define the combination as the PK (generate a surrogate if needed). Instead create a unique index on the columns in a relative order. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=813b209a810c2d05515b9a76f3f9b95b)):

```
create unique index same_cities_uk
    on city_to_city ( least (city1_id,city2_id)
                    , greatest(city1_id,city2_id) 
                    );
```